# Google Chrome caused Mac OS X to have High CPU

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome, big-sur, cpu

[image]

I'm not sure if anyone else faced this issue also. My Mac Book running so hot. I'm on the latest OS BigSur, and on a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). As you can this Mac is fairly new and fully loaded. It's kind of sad when it's hot over an app like **Chrome**, and Apple technician can't find anything wrong it while I brought it to the store twice.

I'm using the default charger that it came with the 16" (96W).

I reinstalled OS twice by me, and by Apple. I tried reset SMC so many times, and it still seems over heat back. I checked Activity Monitor, I saw a lot of **Chrome** extensions.

[image]

How can I make my Mac run like normal again and still able use my Chrome like others ?

I've tried **disaled** a lot of the extensions already, but how do we know which is the one that might have caused these high CPU consumption ? Is there a way to find out ?

**Note**

> When I closed Chrome, my Mac is not hot or loud anymore, so Chrome seem to be the major caused in my case.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't indicaite *very high CPU usage*. Less than 50% is - depending on what you are doing - not much. 100% means that one thread is at max load, but with an 8 core CPU you theoretically (if perfectly multithreaded) have 1600% CPU "capacity" (this is only to give you an idea, not the actual perfect technical explanation of how it **actually** works, but I am just trying to illustrate my point). Can you explain in more details what you are doing with Chrome and if the same thing happens if you use Safari or Firefox?

Comment: I get your points, sometimes I see green screen. I’ll collect more evidence and will update my post with those.

Comment: What do you mean by *green screen*?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1649154/450035

Comment: Have you contacted Chrome support and tried different browsers? Can you test this on another machine?

Comment: Yes. I have tested this in another machine, while my Mac was being analyzing by Apple. I bought another fully loaded machine restore same image on a new one sign in to my chrome account with same plug in installed, that machine also got so hot like  over a few applications opened and one of them was chrome. I used chrome daily as a my dev tool and I hope I can find the solution to this soon because Apple always come back to be with nothing found. It’s on me now, all I have left is you guys ...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. A new MacBook Pro was *still* (after a couple of weeks) running too damn hot. And Chrome was, seemingly, not using a lot of CPU or RAM. And still there were a number of articles and forum posts about how Chrome is still the root of all of this evil.

Being the skeptical type I left Chrome alone. But the heat issue was still there and nothing else was fixing the issue. So I followed some instructions on some web page, somewhere that had some detailed instructions for removing Chrome and all of its little background processes. Google it, you will find quite a few helpful places with detailed instructions.

In its place I installed Brave, which is *based* on Chrome but without all the tracking and auto updating and anything else Google could throw at it.

It worked.

So if you can do without Chrome itself and use Brave in its place you just *may* find that does the trick.

Comment: Wow. I’m sorry that happened to you too. It’s only fews weeks ?? Wow. Even if you left Chrome alone ... issue still there ?

Comment: Have you contact Apple about it ? I doubt they can find anything and we will be back home with a damn hot computer - and cost us almost ~4000$. It’s so sad thinking ab it.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with Apple. It is a Google app and they are solely responsible for how it behaves on the system. What I am saying here is that (on my system) Google Chrome was seemingly causing higher than necessary CPU/RAM/Whatever usage. removing Chrome and all its gubbins solved my issue. YMMV