# Mac OS X running so hot when connecting to a secondary monitor

Tags: macos, big-sur

**MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)**

[image]

I'm not sure if anyone else also experiencing this high CPU on their Mac Book and lead to a really hot fire . I’ve experienced this issue a few months after getting this Mac, since then I experienced it ***every day***.

I’m currently on the latest OS BigSur. As you can this Mac is fairly new and fully loaded.
It's kind of sad when it's hot over an app like **Chrome** or when I connect to a secondary monitor and almost have nothing running at all, and Apple technician can't find anything wrong with it while I brought it to the store ***twice***, and create multiple cases against this Mac. All they say is, they find nothing wrong with it, while I am suffering every day with these types of issues. They suggested me bring it to the store to have it look at, I did that **twice**, and they find nothing twice.

---

## Issues

**kernel_task**

hit 1000%+, Mac OS X freeze and unusable have to kill it via a power button
[image]

---

**Mail**

Sometimes, I saw my Mail hit 170%+

[image]

---

**Green Screen**

During the CPU spike, I noticed my Chrome started to show Green Screen on a certain site, sections of the page, and even if I tried it on a new browser ***[Brave](https://brave.com/)*** - yield identical result.

[image]

More details, I asked here
https://superuser.com/q/1649154

---

## Steps, I took

I tried calling Apple support multiple times, they walked me to reset SMC fan so many times, and it still seems to overheat back (same day). Reset the NV Ram, and not help. They suggested I upgrade the OS. I did that. They suggested I reinstall the OS. Install all apps one by one, I did that. Since I have no luck with Apple so far, I've decided to take matters into your own hands and did these steps :

***Chrome***

removing/disabled chrome extensions that I think it might have something to do with all of these. I asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420770/google-chrome-caused-mac-os-x-to-have-high-cpu).

---

***Mail***

remove any old inbox that I think I don't need in this Mac

---

***Monitors (driver)***

tried with different monitors (34LGUC98 & Dell 34"), with USB-C & HDMI with Apple OEM adapter, while Mac connecting to a default power brick `96W`. It got hot doesn't matter which monitor, or cables, I plugged in.

I've tried to install driver even if I don't think I need

https://www.lg.com/us/support/product/lg-34UC98-W.AUS

---

***Balance Left/Right USB-C Ports***

Yes, thank you for sharing the link in the comment section. I suddenly tried the first solution, and the result still remains hot  and huge lag, even after moving the plug  to the right side.

[image]

---

***Room Temperature***

To clear the doubt on room temperature, I turned on not 1, but `2` humidifiers in my room while it's 81° F which according to [Apple recommended range](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201640#:%7E:text=Use%20your%20Mac%20notebook%20where,and%2095%25%20(noncondensing).) ***(50° and 95° F)***.

[image]

---

***Fan***

I had to sacrifice/broke a fan to make it slanted pointed to my mac keyboard area while using it, so my fingers don't get burned and my Mac won't freeze while working, I don't believe anyone should go through all of these while spending over $4000 on a laptop.

[image]

---

## Next Steps

I'm thinking to call Apple Support again and maybe have them look at my Mac remotely, but it feels like I'm going to stuck in the loop, where they will tell me to do the same things, waste so much of my times, and ended up ... nothing wrong with my mac while it's clearly is.

I just need my Mac to run like normal again

If anyone knows any better solution that I haven't try, please feel free to suggest.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage?

Comment: I tried that and updated my result under ***Balance Left/Right USB-C Ports***

Comment: 1) Does this problem occur when you haven't got anything plugged into the Mac? (i.e. no monitors, no nothing) ... 2) How hot is hot? - I.e. have you measured the actual temperature? ... 3) Does this problem occur when you're booted in Recovery mode? (hold Cmd and R while booting)

Comment: 1) 
If I don't plug in anything at all include the power cord, the heat is definitely reduce because I think the issue kicked in only when I charged, and plug into the 2nd monitor at the same time.



2) 
It's kind of hot where you can touch the section of above the touch bar, but you wouldn't want to leave your fingers there too long. I would like to measure the temperature and let you guys know if I know-how. 




3) 
Let me try that, and will update the post with this result in safe-mode.

Comment: Been fighting this for months! I have found that Chrome can be helped along with an extension called Auto Tab Discard. It will put background tabs to sleep to avoid the constant CPU hit and high RAM usage. Be sure to check the options as it can sometimes sleep tabs you did not want it too. As soon as my new PC comes in, will be moving all web browsing and non-coding to Windows box as Intel Mac can't deal and M1 doesn't have enough RAM :(